# Restarting network not working for a Ubuntu Server Hyper-V instance

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm new to Ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu Sever 17.10 running in a Hyper-V(Windows Host). I am trying to restart the network service without restarting the computer but I keep getting error:

I run this:
sudo service network-manager restart

I get this:
Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.

Any direction is appreciated, tks

Comment: Has the package `network-manager` been installed? Do `apt policy network-manager` and tell us what you get.

Comment: that was it, after installing it it worked (at least it didn't error out). thanks, make it an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a standard Ubuntu Server, `network-manager` would be installed by default, including the file `network-manager.service`. However, in your case, it appears the package wasn't there, wasn't correctly installed, etc. So first, check whether the package has been installed or not:

`apt policy network-manager`

This will tell you if it's there. If not, install it with `sudo apt install network-manager`.

Comment: how would that work if there is no network?

Comment: @matthijsHoekstra If the Network Manager doesn't work, it doesn't mean there is no network, it just isn't managed by that particular app. Of course, if there is no network, you couldn't download any package for installation, but that wasn't the question.